# Mocking a Batch class?

Tags: unit-test, batch, fflib

Is there any way to mock a batch class for unit testing and predefine the scope passed to execute method? I am using a selector class method for Database.getQueryLocator at start method.

```
public class someBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       return new SomeSelectorClass().someMethod();
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
       for(Sobject s : scope){
           doSomething;
       }
       update scope;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically forbidden from mocking batchable class, as noted in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm):

> You can’t mock the following Apex elements.
>
> - Static methods (including future methods)
> - Private methods
> - Properties (getters and setters)
> - Triggers
> - Inner classes
> - System types
> - Classes that implement the Batchable interface
> - Classes that have only private constructors

That said, you can call the methods directly, as it is a normal class. This is typically I might "mock" the batchable:

```
someBatchClass theBatch = new someBatchClass();
sObject[] records = generateRecords(); // do as you will
theBatch.execute(null, records); // And with scope
```

Note that this has the disadvantage of having only the usual synchronous governor limits (10 seconds CPU, 6MB heap) instead of the more generous asynchronous limits. That said, I usually use small batches for testing logic, and larger batches as a "canary in the coalmine" test for slow code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations! I appreciate it.